# Why is IIS forwarding my www request to the TLD without www host name?

Tags: iis, subdomain

I just setup 2 host names in my IIS web-site identity advanced configuration tab.

They are:
port 80 www.mydomain.com
port 80 mydomain.com

Whenever I go to www.mydomain.com it forwards me to mydomain.com

How do I fix it so that it's the other way around, all requests go to www.mydomain.com?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably happening in your application, there is no automated function to do this in IIS.  But if you really don't think it is your application, then look at the Home tab and see if one has redirect selected.